Navbar hovering font color in listed items
I have a navbar on a website, of which I want the background color to be yellow and the text black. When having a mouse over an item, the background would be black and the text yellow.
My problem is that the text returns to black when moving the mouse outside of the text, but still within the boxed "li"-item, resulting in a black background and black text. This causes problems for example where the hovered dropdown title ("MORE") turns to black, and the background also remains in black when moving the mouse onto the listed items (see picture).

I know it's because of a = black and a:hover = yellow, so when the mouse is off the text (a), it returns to black, but I can't get my head around on how to have the "a" remain yellow inside the hovered "li" item, even though the mouse is not on top of the text.
Note: I'm also using Spynav and StickNav on the website, which is the reason for the structure of my code. I just left them out to be more clear to read


.nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.nav a {
  color: black;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}


/* DROPDOWN MENU */

.dropdown-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MORE</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="discography">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>



I have tried having the text color of the hovered li-item yellow, and the background black, as I'd love to think it would work like this.
.nav li:hover{
  color:yellow !important;
  background-color: black;
}


Perhaps the text (an element) inside the li element does not maintain the focus style when the mouse is not directly over it. Try to ensure that the a element within the hovered li inherits the hover style even when the mouse is not directly over it.

Change the selector .nav a:hover into .nav li:hover > a
Then each hovered menu item becomes yellow-on-black, and the items in the sub-menu stay black-on-yellow, until they themselves also get hovered. (That's how you want it, right?)


.nav {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.nav a{
    color: black;
}

.nav li:hover > a{
    color:yellow;
}

.nav li:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU */
.dropdown-content {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MORE</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="discography">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>



